# rtl8821ce-dkms returning exit status 10

Tags: kernel

austin@pop-os:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for austin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rtw88-dkms (0.6~jammy28) ...
Removing old rtw88-0.6~ppa DKMS files...
Deleting module rtw88-0.6~ppa completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new rtw88-0.6~ppa DKMS files...
Building for 6.0.6-76060006-generic
Building initial module for 6.0.6-76060006-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.6-76060006-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtw88/0.6~ppa/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtw88-dkms (--configure):
installed rtw88-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu11pop1~1659015671~22.04~5417fc0) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Deleting module rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 6.0.6-76060006-generic
Building initial module for 6.0.6-76060006-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006-generic is not
supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.6-76060006-generic (x86
_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
rtw88-dkms
rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
austin@pop-os:~$

Comment: Pop_OS is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Im in the same situation. Updated about a week ago and have been troubleshooting ever since. Would love a solution.

**UPDATE** I found a solution:
https://medium.com/@kimiyukiyukawa/installing-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-335d8ccb8a92

-this will link you to a github site with a master file for the rtl8821ce driver. after downloading the file, extract to downloads and rename file in Downloads folder as suggested.

-before running code the codes provided, you must first clear out the old packages. For this run the following codes:

```
   $sudo apt remove --purge rtw8821-dkms
   $sudo apt remove --purge rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Then, to confirm there are no errors, run this code:

```
   $sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then, run the code suggested on my linked site.

After reboot, I had wifi again. Goodluck.

**UPDATE** This does not appear to be a perfect fix, as it is from a year ago and my adapter seems to disconnect/reconnect frequently, but at least I have internet now